# Gamedev rust, how to make this function move efficient

Tags: rust, game-development

Im coding a classic snake game in rust using macroquad. im loving the language and its game engines.

i wrote this `update` function, its called every frame and it moves the snake head,im still new to rust and game programming and i am asking for advice on this function because im feeling that its ineffecient due to me using 4 match statements,and would like to hear advice on it

```
pub fn update(&mut self, dt: f32) {
    let (v_mv, h_mv): (Option<MoveMode>, Option<MoveMode>) = match (
        is_key_down(KeyCode::Down),
        is_key_down(KeyCode::Up),
        is_key_down(KeyCode::Right),
        is_key_down(KeyCode::Left),
    ) {
        (true, false, false, false) => (Some(MoveMode::MovingDown), None),
        (false, true, false, false) => (Some(MoveMode::MovingUp), None),
        (false, false, true, false) => (None, Some(MoveMode::MovingRight)),
        (false, false, false, true) => (None, Some(MoveMode::MovingLeft)),
        _ => (None, None),
    };

    match v_mv {
        Option::Some(MoveMode::MovingUp) => self.move_mode = MoveMode::MovingUp,
        Option::Some(MoveMode::MovingDown) => self.move_mode = MoveMode::MovingDown,
        _ => (),
    };
    match h_mv {
        Option::Some(MoveMode::MovingLeft) => self.move_mode = MoveMode::MovingLeft,
        Option::Some(MoveMode::MovingRight) => self.move_mode = MoveMode::MovingRight,
        _ => (),
    };
    match self.move_mode {
        MoveMode::MovingDown => self.player.y += dt * PLAYER_SPEED * 1f32,
        MoveMode::MovingUp => self.player.y += dt * PLAYER_SPEED * -1f32,
        MoveMode::MovingLeft => self.player.x += dt * PLAYER_SPEED * -1f32,
        MoveMode::MovingRight => self.player.x += dt * PLAYER_SPEED * 1f32,
    }
    debug!("Move Mode is {:?}", self.move_mode);
}
```

the `MoveMode` enum and `Player` struct:

```
struct Player {
player: Rect,
move_mode: MoveMode,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum MoveMode {
MovingUp,
MovingDown,
MovingLeft,
MovingRight,
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this, eliminating the two middle matches:

```rust
        let move_mode = match (
            is_key_down(KeyCode::Down),
            is_key_down(KeyCode::Up),
            is_key_down(KeyCode::Right),
            is_key_down(KeyCode::Left),
        ) {
            (true, false, false, false) => Some(MoveMode::MovingDown),
            (false, true, false, false) => Some(MoveMode::MovingUp),
            (false, false, true, false) => Some(MoveMode::MovingRight),
            (false, false, false, true) => Some(MoveMode::MovingLeft),
            _ => None,
        };
    
        if let Some(move_mode) = move_mode {
            self.move_mode = move_mode;    
        }
        
        match self.move_mode {
            MoveMode::MovingDown => self.player.y += dt * PLAYER_SPEED * 1f32,
            MoveMode::MovingUp => self.player.y += dt * PLAYER_SPEED * -1f32,
            MoveMode::MovingLeft => self.player.x += dt * PLAYER_SPEED * -1f32,
            MoveMode::MovingRight => self.player.x += dt * PLAYER_SPEED * 1f32,
        }
```